# How to calculate the average from the list arrays in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have two arrays as follows,

```
double[] array_a = new [] {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
double[] array_b = new [] {4.0, 5.0, 6.0};
```

which are now added into a list,

```
List<double[]> arrayList = new List<double[]>();

arrayList.Add(array_a);
arrayList.Add(array_b);
```

Now I want to calculate the average from the list arrays (`arrayList`), what would be the best way?

Thanks for your time..:)

Comment: arrayList.SelectMany(x => x).Average()

Answer (score 1):

```
arrayList.SelectMany(n => n).Average()
```

The `SelectMany` call will "flatten" the array.